# add shortcuts to android keyboard via phonegap

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

How is it possible do control the android keyboard shortcuts via phonegap like adding a list of characters on the top of the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I never have done this or something similar, but with a little search for 'cordova plugin keybord' I have found: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard

You can active shrinkView add a view onShow.

If this don't fill the requirement, you may need to create a custom cordova plugin...

Comment: Thanks in advance for your input. Indeed. I've seen applications that use the Android native API to show and hide buttons from the keyboard. Although I can't find any plugin in order to add this feature to phonegap. I'm unfamiliar with the the Android API and with the iOS one. Another point is that the plugin only supports iOS.